# Как вывести название переменной объекта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, классы, функции

Что можно подставить вместо `self` в последней строке кода, чтобы выводилось название переменной объекта?

```
class car:
    def __init__(self,color,mark):
        self.c=color
        self.m=mark
        print('Экземпляр',self,'содержит параметры:',color,mark)
```

Comment: Объект не знает в какую переменную его записали.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю ваш вопрос, это реализовать не получится, потому что в момент создания экземпляра класса, например `a = car()` переменная `a` находится вне области видимости класса и конструктору ее имя никак не передать. Можно, например, в конструктор добавить еще одну переменную `name`, которой вы будете давать такое же имя, что и экземпляру:

```
class car:
    def __init__(self, name, color, mark):
        self.name = name
        self.c = color
        self.m = mark
        print('Экземпляр', name, 'содержит параметры:', color, mark)


Car_1 = car('Car_1', 'red', 'bmw') # Экземпляр Car_1 содержит параметры: red bmw
```

Или просто называть переменную-экземпляр так же как параметр `mark`, например.
В любом случае, поправьте меня, если я ошибаюсь.

Comment: cпасибо за ответ!с практической точки зрения такой способ подходит,но я просто хотел понять,возможно ли как-то обратиться к названию объекта непосредственно

Answer (score 2):

Если вы создали экземпляр класса `car`

```
с = car("red", "Zhiguli")
```

и вы хотите напечатать, как называется класс (`car`),
то вы начинаете с `self` (уже есть:),
потом обращаетесь к классу этого этого экземпляра `self.__class__`,
а потом обращаетесь к имени класса `self.__class__.__name__`.

Answer (score 1):

```
class car:
    def __init__(self,color,mark):
        self.c=color
        self.m=mark
        print('Экземпляр',self.__class__.__name__,'содержит параметры:',color,mark)

car('red','3')
```

Вывод:
`Экземпляр car содержит параметры: red 3`

Comment: Вы выводите имя класса а не экземпляра (переменной) класса. То есть после строки кода `a = car('red', 'bmw')` вывод должен быть `Экземпляр a содержит параметры: red bmw`